# Finding $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n}{1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots+\frac1{2n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

I need to compute:  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}$.

**My Attempt**: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{2s}{s}=2$.

Is that ok?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  } $?

Comment: What is $s$, and where does the first equality come from?

Comment: A couple of posted answers address the problem of how to prove this, one of them by linking to a Wikipedia article and the other by giving a hint as to how to do another proof.  Neither of them says whether the proposed proof in the original question is ok.  I address _that_ directly in my answer.  See below. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: See also: [What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\right) / \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{2k+1}\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2816227)

Answer (score 9):

By the Stolz-Cesaro theorem from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2n+3}}=2.$$

Comment: so my answer is ok.

Comment: @user1212: That's not enough, though: the proof is at least as important as the result in maths.

Comment: @user1212, but your solution is not ok

Comment: @user1212, what is your $s$? What is your reason? So your answer is not ok.

Comment: @xpaul : If the original poster question is whether his own proof is ok --- and on its face that's how it appears --- then this doesn't answer that.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

The numerator is $H_n$ and the denominator is $H_{2n+1}-\frac12H_n$.

Also,

$$\frac{H_n}{H_{2n+1}-\frac12H_n}=\frac1{-\frac12+\frac{H_{2n+1}}{H_n}}$$

and
$$H_n\sim\ln n$$

Comment: what does this '~' imply?

Comment: [It it a symbol meaning "equivalence", and has a very specific meaning.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) As a matter of fact, here it is used in a somewhat improper and misleading way, as equivalence only really makes sense for the first term of the expansion: writing $H_n \sim_{n\to\infty} \ln n + 48$ would be true as well. ($f\sim_\infty g$ means $f=g+o(1)$, and in many cases it is more conveniently expressed at $\frac{f}{g}\to_\infty 1$.)

Comment: can you explain how to proceed?

Comment: Which part? (how to get the expression ajotatxe wrote in his/her answer, or how to get from what he wrote to the solution?)

Answer (score 5):

If the numerator is always twice the denominator, then this works provided you include a proof of that.  Let's try it when $n=2$:
$$
\frac{1+\frac12}{1+\frac13+\frac15} = \frac{30+15}{30+10+6}= \frac{45}{46}\ne 2.
$$
Let's try it when $n=3$:
$$
\frac{1+\frac12+\frac13}{1+\frac 13+\frac15+\frac17}= \frac{210+105+70}{210+70+42+30} = \frac{385}{352} \ne 2.
$$

Comment: but my attempt is for on infinity.

Comment: Your attempt appears to replace $\displaystyle\frac{1 +\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n}{1+\frac13 +\frac15+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}$ with $\dfrac{2s}s$ and THEN to take the limit as $n\to\infty$.  When you change the given fraction to $(2s)/2$ BEFORE taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, you're saying $(2s)/s$ works for every finite value of $n$.  But it doesn't. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: as $s_1=1=1/3+1/5+...$ and $s_2=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...$ so $2s_2-2s_1=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+...$ so $s_2=2s_1$

Comment: that's not true because i got those sums by taking $n\to\infty$

Comment: The limit is *outside* the ratio, where the quantity $s$ (which, incidentally, you never defined explicitly) appears in both the numerator and denominator. What you write is what @MichaelHardy pointed out: you replace a finite sum by something, *then* take the limit. But the thing you had and what you replaced it with are not equal, so the proof is not valid.

Comment: If you write $s_1=1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots$, that means $\displaystyle s_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots+\frac1n\right)$.  One problem with this is that that sum is $\infty$ rather than any finite number. Another is that you're working on $\displaystyle\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n)}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots+\frac1{2n+1})}$ rather than $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n}{1+\frac13+\frac15+\cdots+\frac1{2n+1}}$.  The latter limit exists and is a finite number.  The former is $\infty/\infty.\quad{}$

Comment: i'm confused because i guess i can solve it by my method but i don't know how to do it correctly by your remarks and the other solutions are hard for me to understand.

Comment: @user1212: the issue with your method is that it is *not* a valid proof: the "sum" $s$ you are using is infinite, and you cannot apply mathematical operations on it as you do.

Comment: @user1212 : Something you should know about limits is that if $f\to\infty$ and $g\to\infty$, then in some cases $\lim\dfrac f g$ exists and is a finite number, but $\dfrac{\lim f}{\lim g}$ just gives $\dfrac\infty\infty$, so that doesn't work as a way of finding the limit.  The same sort of thing often happens when $f\to0$ and $g\to0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: now i got it, thank you for your Patience.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's still any interest in this question from more than a year ago, but here's an elementary solution:

The numerator in the problem is $H_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac{1}{n},$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ harmonic number.

The denominator in the problem is

\begin{align}
1+\frac13+\frac15+\dots+\frac1{2n+1}&=H_{2n+1}-\big(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}\big)
\\&=H_{2n+1}-\frac12 \big(1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac{1}{n}\big)
\\&=H_{2n+1}-\frac12 H_n.
\end{align}

Next note that
\begin{align}
H_{2n+1}-H_n&=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n+1}
\\&\le\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+1} \scriptsize{\quad(n+1\text{ terms})}
\\&=1.
\end{align}

Of course, $H_{2n+1}-H_n$ is always positive, being a sum of one or more positive fractions, so we have

$$0\lt H_{2n+1}-H_n \le 1$$

for all non-negative integers $n.$

Since $H_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty,$ it follows that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_{2n+1}-H_n}{H_n}=0.
$$

We can now solve the original problem:

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty  }\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{H_{2n+1}-\frac12 H_n}
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_n}{\frac12 H_n+(H_{2n+1}-H_n)}
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac12+\frac{H_{2n+1}-H_n}{H_n}}
\\&=\frac{1}{\frac12+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_{2n+1}-H_n}{H_n}}
\\&=\frac{1}{\frac12+0}
\\&=2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

With the Euler-MacLaurin formula, we have

numerator = $\ln(n)+O(1)$ and denominator = $\frac12 \ln(2n+1) + O(1)$, so the limit is

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n)+O(1)}{\frac12 \ln(2n+1) + O(1)}= 2.$