# Summation Notation using Induction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}$$

I am trying to prove this inductively, so I thought that I would expand the right side out of sigma form to get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{2}{2n(2n+1)} - \frac{1}{n}$$

which simplified to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \frac{-2}{2n+1}$$

but apparently that isn't correct, can someone provide some insight into what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The second equation, how did you expand it out of sigma form?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k =  \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$ so I flipped that upside down as the k was in the denominator, replaced every k with 2n and subtracted the first term, $$\frac{(1)}{n}$$ to make the lower limit k = 1

Comment: That's what it looked like you were doing, and what I alluded to in my answer.  You can't flip over a sum: $\frac1{a+b}$ doesn't equal $\frac1{a}+\frac1{b}.$

Answer (score 1):

The right side doesn't equal what you think it equals.  I think maybe you're confusing this with the different, and unrelated, formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$  You can't get from that formula to a formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k}$ or anything similar.

See [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1961771/35021](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1961771/350214) for a detailed answer to your question.  (The question in the other post is phrased as a limit, but the answer there solves your problem exactly.)

Answer (score 1):

> **INDUCTION PROOF:**

If one wishes to prove the identity using induction, we first establish a benchmark.  Letting $n=1$, we find that $\sum_{k=1}^{2}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=1/2=\sum_{k=2}^2\frac1k$.

Next, we assume that the identity works for some number $n$

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}}=\color{red}{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k} \tag 1$$

Then, we test the validity of the relationship in $(1)$ for $n+1$.  Proceeding we find that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}&=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\\\\
&=\color{red}{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k}+\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}\frac1k+\frac{1}{n+1}-\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}\frac1k
\end{align}$$

as expected.

---

> **DIRECT PROOF:**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{2k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!